# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'progress_bar_refresh_rate'

Tags: error-handling, pytorch, arguments

I tried resolving this issue since two days however still facing this issue any leads would be helpful.
[Please refer the link for screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8WAj.png)

Comment: Can you show you argparser definition?

Answer (score 7):

Please try by deleting the `progress_bar_refresh_rate=5` argument, since this keyword argument is no longer supported by the latest version (1.7.0) of PyTorch.Lightning.Trainer module. [Check this screenshot for clarity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spFhz.png).

Comment: I tried that but deleting that line didn't resolve the problem

Comment: @JigyasaSinghh Do not delete the entire line, just the mentioned argument. You may need to revise the Trainer class as per the latest Pytorch lightening updates.

Answer (score 0):

I delete the `progress_bar_refresh_rate=5`, but there are other issues came out.
Finally, I solved this problem by downgrading my pytorch_lightning library version.
You can input the following command in your conda bash `pip install pytorch_lightning==1.5`